# What is the difference between submit() and offer() in a SubmissionPublisher (Java Reactive Streams)

Tags: java, reactive-streams

What I have read so far indicates the the `submit()` method is blocking "while resources for any subscriber are unavailable" (not sure what exactly that means).

Hence I tried the following:

```
    var publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<String>(ForkJoinPool.commonPool(), 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < publisher.getMaxBufferCapacity() + 2; i++) {
        publisher.submit("item" + i);
    }
    publisher.close();
```

So I am submitting 3 items, there is **no subscriber** and still there is no blocking happening. The for-loop exits after three loops.

So what is the difference between `submit` and `offer`, about which people write it would "not block"?

Comment: Looking at and experimenting with the class, `submit` will only block if there is at least one subscriber whose buffer is at capacity. Note the buffers are per subscription. The publisher itself has no buffer. So, it appears this implementation does not buffer items for _future_ subscribers. If there are no subscribers when you submit an item, that item is simply "lost".